# How to bind local variable in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have silverlight usercontrol. This contains Service Entity object. see below

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
   public ServiceRef.tPage CurrentPage { get; set; }
...
}
```

I need to bind `CurrentPage.Title` to TextBox

My xaml is here

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CurrentPage.Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"></TextBox>
```

But it is not work.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for that to work, you'll have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your class and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for `CurrentPage` when it's set (this also means you won't be able to use auto properties; you'll have to use your own private instance backing variable and code the `get { }` and `set { }` yourself).

What's happening is the control is binding to the value before you've set `CurrentPage`. Because you aren't notifying anyone that the property has changed, it does not know to refresh the bound data. Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` will fix this.

Or you could just manually set the `Text` property yourself in the setter.

Comment: Thereupon I must implement Entity class (tPage) from `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. That's True?
If my understand is true, How to implement all entity class automatically? Because entity classes generated automatically

Comment: @ebattulga: If by "Entity" you mean an ADO.NET Entity Framework entity, then they already implement this interface.

Answer (score 0):

Change your markup to

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=CurrentPage.Title}" />
```

By assigning `RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}` your are telling the `TextBlock` to bind to itself and look for a property named `CurrentPage` on the `TextBlock` itself and not the parent `Window`.

Answer (score 0):

set the `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` in the XAML.